# IntelliJ - Persistence QL Queries error-check over hibernate queries

Tags: hibernate, intellij-idea

I have hibernate session query using a class recognized by hibernate. This query runs smoothly but is somehow recognized by IntelliJ IDEA as a Persistence QL Queries error - "Cant resolve symbol"

[image: Persistence QL Queries error]

I know how to disable Persistence QL Queries error-check in IntelliJ inspection options, but is there a way to avoid the error in some other way?

(I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 9.0.3)

Comment: Looks like you don't have a valid hibernate Facet/descriptors configuration in your project.

Comment: This might be true. Where do i define hibernate Facet/descriptors configuration ?

Comment: Refer to help: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/hibernate.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems IDEA doesn't recognize which or what Descriptor you are using.
Check Project Structure -> Facets -> Hibernate. You should have found a cfg.xml file in Descriptors. If you are using package scanning through spring session factory definition,you should have found a session factory bean. If neither of them exists,you may add one.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check Project Structure -> Facets -> Hibernate
   2- if you have not a cfg.xml file, you should add new one.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the @Entity annotation in your model