# Intellij IDea 15 Using the @ Query error

Tags: java, intellij-idea, spring-data

Using the Spring-Data-Jpa framework

Below is my code:

```
 @Repository(value = "ser")
 public interface ServiceConfigRepository extends CrudRepository<ServiceConfig, Serializable> {

      @Query("select ser from ServiceConfig ser where ser.valid <> '启用'")
      public ServiceConfig findByVaild(String vild);
}
```

In the code above ServiceConfig have errors, but normal operation. How to get rid of the warning?

Comment: What is the warning? It's an intellij idea linter warning?

Comment: Could you please provide more information regarding the mentioned warning and the `@Query` error?

Comment: @MarcoAcierno   : This inspection controls whether the Persistence QL Queries are error-checked , This is a warning

Comment: @aribeiro : This inspection controls whether the Persistence QL Queries are error-checked , This is a warning

Comment: @beansprouts, have you looked at the following answers: [IntelliJ - Persistence QL Queries error-check over hibernate queries](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9731483/1346996) or [Intellij how to correctly configure hql with spring boot. Now i get Persistence QL Queries are error-checked](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34178738/1346996)?

Comment: With 'get rid' you mean fixing the warning or disabling it? (to disable, https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html)

Comment: @MarcoAcierno : Disabled after warning disappears , thx

Comment: @aribeiro : these two posts have similar reasons , thx